why mongose docReducer function in __getAllSubdocs taking hgh cpu even if document is not an embedded doc?
In the Mongoose lib CPU profiling, I noticed that docReducer function present in document.js is consuming 30% of CPU resources. Upon further investigation, I found that during document save call, there are multiple calls to __getAllSubdocs, which in turn calls docReducer. This function recursively checks each key in the document to see if there are embedded documents. However, my collection does not contain embedded documents, and I would like to avoid this overhead. Is there a flag to skip the docReducer call, or do you guys have any suggestions on how to handle this? Or what can be done here?
Shall i comment the code var subDocs = Object.keys(this._doc).reduce(docReducer.bind(this), []); and simply return []; ?
In latest mongo version docReducer funtion is optimised but its still there with big overhead.
Document.prototype.$__getAllSubdocs = function() {
    DocumentArray || (DocumentArray = require('./types/documentarray'));
    Embedded = Embedded || require('./types/embedded');

  function docReducer(seed, path) {
    var val = this[path];

    if (val instanceof Embedded) {
      seed.push(val);
    }
    
    if (val && val.$isSingleNested) {
      seed = Object.keys(val._doc).reduce(docReducer.bind(val._doc), seed);
      seed.push(val);
    }
    
    if (val && val.isMongooseDocumentArray) {
      val.forEach(function _docReduce(doc) {
        if (!doc || !doc._doc) {
          return;
        }
        if (doc instanceof Embedded) {
          seed.push(doc);
        }
        seed = Object.keys(doc._doc).reduce(docReducer.bind(doc._doc), seed);
      });
    } else if (val instanceof Document && val.$__isNested) {
      if (val) {
        seed = Object.keys(val).reduce(docReducer.bind(val), seed);
      }
    }
    
    return seed;
  }

  var subDocs = Object.keys(this._doc).reduce(docReducer.bind(this), []); 
  return subDocs; 
// shall i comment var subDocs = Object.keys(this._doc).reduce(docReducer.bind(this), []);  ? and return []
};

  

